# Getting around the Lenovo BIOS whitelist

Tags: bios, whitelist, ghidra

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad that only allows certain hardware to be installed. If there is a piece of hardware connected that is not on the whitelist, BIOS will tell you to remove it and restart. Otherwise the machine will not boot. Now I want to install an unauthorized wifi+bluetooth module, so I need to get rid of that whitelist.

I've been following [this guide](https://medium.com/@p0358/removing-wlan-wwan-bios-whitelist-on-a-lenovo-laptop-to-use-a-custom-wi-fi-card-f6033a5a5e5a) up to the point where the author suggests the use of the IDA pro software, which I don't want to buy just for this one hack.

Instead, I have dabbled around a bit with the extracted body in Ghidra, and managed to get to locate the hex code for the "Unauthorized network card detected ..." string and to find out that the string is part of some entity called "DAT_000104d0", and the only place that entity is referenced is the following function:

```
void FUN_00010ec4(undefined8 param_1,undefined *param_2,undefined8 param_3,undefined8 param_4)

{
   if (param_2 == (undefined *)0x0) {
     param_2 = &DAT_00010ec0;
  }
  (**(code **)(DAT_00011040 + 0x170))(0x200,param_1,param_2,param_3,&DAT_000104d0,param_4);
  return;
}
```

That function in turn gets called from here:

```
longlong entry(undefined8 param_1,longlong param_2)

{
  longlong lVar1;
  undefined8 local_res18;
  undefined8 *local_res20;
  undefined local_18 [24];

  FUN_00010f08(param_1,param_2);
  lVar1 = (**(code **)(DAT_00011040 + 0x140))(&LAB_00010480,0,&DAT_00011058);
  if (-1 < lVar1) {
    lVar1 = (**(code **)(DAT_00011040 + 0x140))(&LAB_00010410,0,&DAT_00011070);
    if (-1 < lVar1) {
      lVar1 = (**(code **)(DAT_00011040 + 0x140))(&DAT_000103f0,0,&DAT_00011078);
      if (-1 < lVar1) {
        lVar1 = (**(code **)(DAT_00011040 + 0x140))(&LAB_00010460,0);
        if (-1 < lVar1) {
          DAT_00011060 = *local_res20;
          local_res18 = 0;
          _DAT_00011068 = &LAB_00010b54;
          (**(code **)(DAT_00011040 + 0x80))(&local_res18,&DAT_000103d0,0,&DAT_00011068);
          DAT_00011028 = local_res18;
          FUN_00010ec4(0x10,FUN_00010cf8,0,local_18);
          lVar1 = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return lVar1;
}
```

Any idea on how I should proceed, hopefully without messing up the whole thing?

I've uploaded the complete bios img and the extracted body [here](https://c.gmx.net/@324492825821451320/FEFfHieaT2uKXWqWaCpFKQ), if anyone wants to have a look at those.

---

Edit: I used a workaround by googling a lot and eventually finding a modified version of the extracted body that I used experimentally, and it worked. What I googled for was (I think) the name of that section of the BIOS. In the example from the medium guide that would be 11D37... That number will be different for your device though, and I can´t guarantee that there will be such a file for your device at all, or that it will work. Just make sure you backup your original bios multiple times and in multiple places, so you can flash it again.